# how to properly remove a property from an object in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I write next generic, but maybe someone knows a more correct solution

```
const deleteKeyFromObject = <T extends {}, K extends keyof T>(data: T, key: K) => {
  const result : any = { ...data };
  delete result[key];

  return result as Omit<T, K>;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a better way:

```
const deleteKeyFromObject = <T extends {}, K extends keyof T>(data: T, key: K) => {
  const { [key]: _, ...result } = data;
  return result;
}
```

The type of `result` is correctly inferred as `Omit<T, K>`.

Comment: Thank you, I realized that I do not need a separate function, I can use:   const { omitKey: _, ...result } = data;